# Trying to change android Gridview to horizontal paging or scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, pagination, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling

i am a complete beginner to android app development.
i have successfully created an simple contacts app in android studio.
now i have been given a task to switch from vertical view to horizontal scroll or paging view.
i have been on this for three weeks now, but i am not being able to progress any bit.

i am trying to implement the following example in my project.
http://shrikantsonarblogs.blogspot.in/
Android GridView with ViewPager

BUT being a newbie i am not being able to do what i wanted to do. (maybe because of my incomplete understaing)

please someone be kind to help me, please.
this is important for career

Link to complete android studio project 
[Android simple Contacts app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjscxseaco61tsj/ContactDatabase.rar?dl=0)

Comment: hold on bro...I am looking into the matter...

Answer (score 0):

**Have a look at this project on github**

https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview/blob/master/sample/res/layout/main.xml

It's exactly got what you want to accomplish.

**You will want to use**

```
app:scrollDirectionPortrait="vertical"
app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
```

Get the whole project down and try running it, and implement it in your own project!

Comment: yes, thank you for the suggestion, i have seen this option, but Fristly, i have to do the code in my own project rather than using other projects, i need to know and learn from it. And secondly, i have not been able to successfully import that Two-Way project. All i am hoping is for someone to check my project and provide me some code or class by editing my project, so that i can learn from them.

Comment: you are in the wrong place bro! Try posting the exactly code where you are having trouble, you can't just post the whole project and look for answers!